# Which flow should I use?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am making application which should by used by company and should be used for sharing documents, approvals of the documents, special events and other things for that company... 
I read that implicit flow is better for JS appps.. but
I would use Spring boot and jQuery for Front-End and that application should be used only by employees of that company... so basically It should not be that difficult to safely store "secret" for them... So I am thinking about code grant flow instead...

1) Which flow should I use in your opinion please?
2) Where should be stored "client_id" and secret safely?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code flow is more secure than implicit flow, but technically more complicated.

your questions:

1. code flow is more secure, more security always better but also takes more time to implement.
2. using implicit flow there is no client_id and secret, since you delegate the logging in to the authentication server.

if you use code flow, you have to have an intermediate service between your app and the authorization server. Thats where you store your client_id and secret. This is usually called a "BFF" or "Backend for frontend".